# How can I update multiple configuration fields of a composer environment at once?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-composer

When I try to run `gcloud composer environments update` and specify `--update-labels` and `--update-env-variables` I get an error:

```
Composer deployment failed with error: ERROR: (gcloud.composer.environments.update) Exactly one 
of (.....) must be specified.
```

That is a very frustrating limitation for automation purposes.

Is this a limitation of the cli or the API proper? I want my deployment scripts to make it possible to update multiple values and I really don't want to have to loop over all options and make a call for each one- even if I can use `--async`.

I wasn't able to find answers in the docs. Can I get around this by calling the API programmatically with the SDK?

Comment: The error you encountered is a limitation of the gcloud CLI for Google Cloud Composer's environments.update command. When using this command, you can only update one type of setting (labels, environment variables, etc.) per invocation.

Answer (score 1):

Would this command be applicable to your use case? I tried just repeating the command with update env variable and update labels:

```
user@cloudshell:~ (my-project)$ gcloud composer environments update \
    samplenestor \
    --location us-central1 \
    --update-env-variables=SAMPLEKEY=700
gcloud composer environments update \
    samplenestor \
    --location us-central1 \
    --update-labels samplelabel=guitar
```

Result: [image]

**UPDATE:**

It appears that this is a limitation for [Cloud Composer](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.locations.environments/patch#query-parameters) at the moment hence the error mentioned in the question:

> Only one update type may be included in a single request's updateMask. For example, one cannot update both the PyPI packages and labels in the same request.

For the mean time I have created a feature request/issue tracker for this inquiry that can be followed for updates:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/296867228

Comment: No my whole point was asking if I could avoid exactly this: "I really don't want to have to loop over all options and make a call for each one". Also every update does a composer restart and takes 4+ minutes.

Comment: You are right, It appears that this is currently a limitation for cloud Composer at the moment, will update my answer.

Comment: So this is a limitation of composer itself not just the cli it seems. If I were to use the SDK to do this I'd run into the same issue.